# Подскажите где ошибка в моем коде удаления вершины из бинарного дерева?

Tags: java

Пытался реализовать метод удаления вершины из бинарного дерева. Проблема в том, что когда я хочу удалить корень дерева он не удаляется, подскажите где ошибка.

```
private static Node delete(Node n, int x) {
        if(n == null) return n;
        if (x > n.x) n.r = delete(n.r, x);
        else if (x < n.x) n.l = delete(n.l, x);
        else if (n.r != null && n.l != null) {
            n.x = n.r.minimum().x;
            n.r = delete(n.r, n.r.x);
        }
        else {
            if (n.r != null) n = n.r;
            else n = n.l;
        }
        return n;
    }
    public void remove(int x){
        delete(this, x);
    }
```

Comment: `Node.remove` в таком виде бесполезен. Допустим, у вас есть только корневая вершина со значением 5, вы вызываете `корень.remove(5)`, метод вызывает `delete(this, 5)`, который честно возвращает `null` (`корень.l`), который никак не используется. Можно завести класс `Tree`, у которого будет поле `root`, и метод `remove(int x) { root = delete(root, x); }`.

Comment: remove работает, когда беру не корень, когда беру корень, дебагер все норм показывает, но в самом ответе получаю ту же ссылку

Comment: @Артем, если вопрос для вас больше не актуален, то выберите ответ, который по вашему мнению был наиболее исчерпывающим (галочка слева от ответа) и тогда вопрос можно будет считать закрытым.Если вы не нашли среди ответов нужный, предложите свой вариант ответа, который раскрывал бы суть вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В книге "Алгоритмы построение и анализ" Томас Кормен. 
Разобран алгоритм удаления узла из бинарного дерева поиска.

Процедура удаления разделена на две подпрограммы, являющиеся псевдокодом.
Первая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вторая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где T- ссылка на ваше дерево, z- ссылка на узел который нужно удалить. 
Полагаю, зная этот алгоритм, для вас не составит труда написать его реализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно строку

```
n.r = delete(n.r, n.r.x);
```

заменить на

```
n.r = delete(n.r, n.x);
```

т.к. иначе вы удаляете не искомое, а ноду справа